# better place for sensitive temp file, ram disk or hdd or ssd?

Tags: ram, disk, temp

my app saves a 1MB file and then another app reads it back. After that I want to sercure delete it. I thought about a ram drive because I know that even with a secure delete appl. something would remain on HDD or SSD. I can accept to lose the content of that file on shutdown. The fact is that I read about some bugs in some ram disk applications bug lists(ex.: imdisk) related to file corruption. Solved bugs but I'm wondering if ram disk apps are secure from file integrity point of view. On the other hand neither a normal disk is 100% secure. My temp file is absolutely important for me. I also protect my file through a sha1 or similar, but let's suppose for a moment that there is no protection, just to understand what is the best solution.
Thanks
Pupillo

Comment: You should really rephrase your question. If you care about the quality of ramdisks in general or in imdisk in specific.

Answer (score 0):

What storage place is best certainly depends on the hardware involved, amongst others their age, their MTTF and any previous failures encountered.
I don't think it is possible to give a general answer.

Sounds to me like you are looking for an IPC mechanism, like shared memory.
This would also avoid using file systems and their -- imo very rare -- bugs.

If you think about file corruptions you should also think what will happen on crashes of the involved applications.
So you might have multiple problems:

1. IPC
2. Persistency on crashes
3. Security concerncs, e.g. others reading the involved sections of RAM/HD

Comment: Let me simplify my question. I usually use my hdd /ssd to store a sensitive 1MB temp file. I'm thinking to move to a ram disk. Should I be MORE concerned about file integrity? No concerns about shutdown or crashes

Comment: I understood your question perfectly well but it does not make sense. You either want IPC, persistency or both. Using file systems for IPC is often a bad idea, independent of the used file system. So what do you care about? The quality of RAM, the quality of imdisk, ...?

Comment: I want only IPC but my app can handle only files. I'd prefer a ram disk to get my file wiped on shutdown, but I care about possible bugs in the ram disk driver.